# AWS Api gateway greedy path takes over static route issue

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-rest-api

I have an AWS Api gateway with Rest API configured. There are 2 resources configured

1. **POST** /v1/operations/init - this is the static route
2. **ANY** /v1/{proxy+} - this is the greedy.

Greedy path (no.2) requires API KEY but not the static one. When I try the request on static route (POST /v1/operations/init) it returns **200 OK and "Missing Authentication token"**

My question: is existence of the path in both resources the problem?

Comment: According  to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html it should work. I had an issue with this, but it turned out that I hadn't deployed the latest changes to resources. Maybe this was the case here?